# How to use Actionbar Tabs and Actionbar Spinner at the same time?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner, android-tabs

I want to implement app which will download data and set it into ActionBar Tabs. I've already implemeted it, but I have one more thing to do. I've tried to add actionbar list, like this [one](http://s019.radikal.ru/i629/1303/c4/235b72c6d0ff.png), but android doesn't allow to use Tabs and List at the same time :( After pressing on one of the items in List, application should download corresponding data and fit it into my app. ([Example](https://lh6.ggpht.com/jZa9O5rEm_GW1UdjTig-Vo9tlaHXIzbET2s2HllWd3RAgh8Ot5C6pxG8hrVKv80VVED4)) So how could I do that? Is there any way to fit spinner in Action Bar? if yes, please provide example.

Answer (score 1):

**I could do it this way:**

```
bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

navigation is **tabs**, but the ActionBar has a custom view.

```
bar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);
bar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

That `custom_actionbar` contains the `spinner`.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Could you provide example of ActionBar custom view (xml)?

Comment: ActionBar custom view is no different from any other layout. just have a spinner or some imageview in a layout and use it as the custom view to your action bar. try it yourself.